# Finding the percentage of y out of x for an Android App

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to create an app that finds Y out of X is P%.

For example, if Bob has 50 students in class and 20 of them get C's what percentage of them got C's.

I have worked out code that finds Y is P% of X but I can't figure out how to get the percentage of two numbers

```
/*public void onClick(View view) {
            float percentage = Float.parseFloat(edtP.getText().toString());
            float dec = percentage / 100;
            float total = dec * Float.parseFloat(edtN.getText().toString());
            tv.setText(Float.toString(total));*/
```

So using the example I want the code to be able to take values inserted by the user so in the example I gave 20 students of 50 got a C giving us the value of 40%. I want the user to be able to see the end value.

Comment: so let's say 200 students in total, 20 got C---> you want to show to user 10% got C. Am I right?

Comment: Correct that's what I'm looking for

Answer (score 0):

Switch division and multiplication.

```
public void onClick(View view) {
            float percentage = Float.parseFloat(edtP.getText().toString());
            float dec = percentage * 100.0;
            float total = dec / Float.parseFloat(edtN.getText().toString());
            tv.setText(Float.toString(total));
}
```

I might have some syntactic error in the above code. I wrote the original in Kotlin. See for reference.

```
        btn.setOnClickListener {
        val cGraders = countCGrades.text.toString().toFloat()
        val totalStudents = totalStudents.text.toString().toFloat()
        val percent = cGraders*100/totalStudents
        result.text = percent.toString()
    }
```